# NextJs empty query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a NextJs application that requires a query to be defined in the route (to handle tab navigation), but I am facing a really weird issue where the query would remain default (empty).

```
{
  route: '/list',
  pathname: '/list',
  query: { t: '' },
  asPath: '/list?t=selling'
}
```

Weirdest part is that asPath as the query, while the query object has an empty string.

I am using Next's withRouter.

index.js

```
export default withRouter(
  compose(
    connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      mapDispatchToProps,
    ),
  )(ListPage));
```

ListPage.js

```
const ListPage = ({
  fetchData,
  fetchedData,
  router,
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (t && t !== '') { // always empty, so this never works.
      console.log('t', t);
      fetchData(t);
    }
  }, [t]);

return <div> UI stuff here {fetchedData} </div>;
```

next.config.js

```
     exportPathMap: async (defaultPathMap) => {
        return {
          '/': { page: '/', query: {} },
          '/list': { page: '/list', query: { t: '' } },
```

removing the query: { t: '' } from next.config.js seems to solve the issue.

Comment: For the query to be populated you must provide it to the `href` value not just the `asPath` no ?

Comment: This happens on mount. If I navigate to the page from the url shouldn't the query get populated?

Comment: Additionally I use Router.push({
      pathname: '/list',
      query: { t: 'selling' },
    }), shouldn't this populate the query too?

Comment: The query object will be empty during prerendering if the page is statically optimized.